# Altbeacon BLE Library no detection on Samsung Galaxy A51

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

I am trying to do simple BLE Beacon monitoring using the provided [sample app](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference). I do not get any detections on a Samsung Galaxy A51.

According to the [documentation](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/detection-trouble.html), this is expected since i am using an empty scan filer. What I am struggling with is identifying how and where to apply these scan filters in the provided reference app, as it is using this code:

```java
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        BeaconManager beaconManager = org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setContentTitle("Scanning for Beacons");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MonitoringActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("My Notification Channel ID",
                    "My Notification Name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.setDescription("My Notification Channel Description");
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
                    Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            builder.setChannelId(channel.getId());
        }
        beaconManager.enableForegroundServiceScanning(builder.build(), 456);

        beaconManager.setEnableScheduledScanJobs(false);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100);



        Log.d(TAG, "setting up background monitoring in app onCreate");
        beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(this);

        for (Region region: beaconManager.getMonitoredRegions()) {
            beaconManager.stopMonitoring(region);
        }

        beaconManager.startMonitoring(wildcardRegion);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is no need to manually add a scan filter with the Android Beacon Library.**  The library adds filters automatically as needed for Samsung and other Android models.  Per the documentation, the only time it needs help is if a non-standard beacon is being used that uses a custom manufacturer identifier.  In this rare case the library needs to be told that custom manufacturer identifier for the automatic scan filter to work.

Since this is not what is causing the problem with detections something else must be.  A few suggestions:

1. Use an off the shelf app like BeaconScope that is also based on this library.  Does it detect your beacon?
2. If the answer to the above is no, are you sure the beacon is transmitting and has the format you think?
3. If the answer to (1) is yes, focus first on getting the library’s reference app to work with your beacon, and modify it slowly until it matches the code you have now.

Comment: Hello David, thank you for your insights. How would I know if my beacon is a non-standard one? Where in the provided code would i assign the custom manufacturer identifier?
1. BeaconScope does not detect the beacon on the A51. It does on the Motorola.
2. I am sure the beacon is submitting since the signal is picked up on the motorola device.

Comment: https://ibb.co/hy5m3JB here is a screenshot of the beacon detected on the Motorola device.

Comment: I have found the issue. The devices causing the problems had the global location setting deactived while I only checked for app-specific permissions. Thank you for your help David.

Comment: OK, good.  Yes, the phone setting for location on/off is a key thing to check!